# Cpanel: #1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation

Tags: mysql, cpanel

I get this error

`#1227 - Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation` on enabling mysql event scheduler.

In Cpanel->PhpMyAdmin->database_name->SQL tab

I enter the following code to enable the event scheduler:

`SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;`

But on doing So I get the above error. Is it possible to grant super privileges on the server or is there some other way to create that event?

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you !!

Comment: Do you have super user access to MySQL or are you using a shared hosting cpanel account as a normal / unprivileged user? If the latter you might need someone from you hosting company to help.

Comment: Yes it is a shared hosting.

Answer (score 5):

You are on cPanel. I am taking a wild guess that you are on a shared host. This is how they lock it down.

It is virtualized and super privileges are turned off. This is so you won't go hog wild creating crons, events, and hogging the system. Degradating the experience for everyone.

So, no, you cannot create events. And users are only created thru the rather hokey cPanel interface.

What you are normally allowed to do is create a small handful of crontab tasks.

Were you to identify the hoster, I could investigate it for you. Then again, so could you :p

A typical FAQ page for a hoster may look like the following:

[image]

It was a shock to read the above, but understandable. That is why I have about 90% of my stuff running on Amazon EC2. Full servers (well, full control), any code platform. Sure, hard to manage, but then again I am a devops guy. And a developer. And I want the ability to do anything and everything.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes, it is a shared hosting type.  but do I contact the hosting company and ask them to enable it?

Comment: I hope you have a more flexible host that opens up functionality. So, yes, contact them

Comment: I have contacted them, but there is no global access permitted on shared hosting. I need to find another alternative to mysql event scheduler.

Comment: [cron](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cron) or [ec2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/amazon-ec2) ... I would recommend the latter :p

Comment: I am not on AWS. But are CRONS easy for dynamic queries?

Comment: I am afraid that is where you will be disappointed. They are scheduled command line statements. For some hosts, about the extent of it is running a php executable with a php file extension target. But at least you are into a program then (that connects to your db and runs PHP further PHP programming

Answer (score 0):

From the shell connect to MySQL as an administrator:

```
mysql -u root -p mysql
```

Now on the mysql prompt type:

```
> grant all privileges on DATABASE_NAME.* to USERNAME@localhost identified by 'PASSWORD';
> flush privileges;
> \q
```

You can [read more](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html) about GRANT's syntax at MySQL's site.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I am a bit worried to play around with the server in such a manner.

Comment: @davidnoronha it wouldn't cause any problems or you can just give permissions for event privilage http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_event

Comment: It's alright thanks. I'll contact the hosting company